# ContextMenuStrip LayoutStyle

Tags: vb.net

I am using VB.NET VS2010. I have a toolstrip with a ToolStripDropDownButton.
The dropdown items are created at runtime and all works fine.

The problem is that when there are too many items the small overflow buttons appear which are unusable in touch screen tablets.
I set the LayoutStyle to Flow but cannot get the items to flow.
I have now set the dropdown of the button to a ContextMenuStrip so that I could perhaps customise it better but no matter what I try the LayoutStyle of the ContextMenuStrip stays the same.

How can I get it to flow properly the way the main toolstripitems flow?

Comment: WinForms is just not the best choice when it comes to a touch screen tablet application.

Comment: I know Winforms is not ideal, but the application has been around longer than touch screen tablets and it is too big a job to convert it now.

Comment: I have solved it meantime by using a Syncfusion PopUpControlContainer containing a toolstrip. This gives scrollbars which can be used in a tablet.